# Selecionar ID aleatório entre 2 e 4

Tags: mysql, sql, query

É possivel selecionar aleatoriamente o ID, colocando, por exemplo, os números de ID que podem ser sorteados (2/4)?

Observação: Só deve ser retornada uma linha dessa seleção.

Coloquei esse código mas não foi:

```sql
SELECT descricao
 FROM TABLE
 ORDER BY RAND ID (2,4)
 LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode tentar fazer dessa forma:

```sql
SELECT descricao
 FROM TABLE
 WHERE ID = FLOOR(RAND() * 3 + 2)
 LIMIT 1;
```

A função `RAND()` irá retornar um número aleatório de ponto flutuante entre 0 e 1, ou seja, um número decimal. Para limitar o resultado entre uma faixa de números específica, que inclua tanto o número mínimo quanto o número máximo, você faz a seguinte conta:

```sql
FLOOR( RAND() * (max - min + 1) + min )
```

A função `FLOOR()` vai desconsiderar as casas decimais, retornando apenas a parte inteira de um número decimal.

Fontes:
[MySQL FLOOR() function - w3resource](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mathematical-functions/mysql-floor-function.php)
[MySQL RAND() function - w3resource](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mathematical-functions/mysql-rand-function.php)
[Mysql Rand() between 2 values · GitHub](https://gist.github.com/asika32764/534ad8891a2a3bb8fe05)